# Calculate phone angle (Android)

Tags: android, accelerometer

I know this has been asked before, but I haven't found the answer I am looking for.

All I want to do is hold my phone up at the sky, and know the angle at which I am holding it with respect to the horizon. So if I am holding it directly above me (screen facing ground) then it should read 90 degrees, and if I hold it in front of me (screen facing me), it should   read 0 degrees.

I have fumbled through some basics of getting data from the accelerometer and I believe I have the X, Y and Y values from it. How can I take those points and find my angle? Below is my OnSensorChanged event that I gather the coordinate from.

```
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
   mGravity = event.values;
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
   mGeomagnetic = event.values;
if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
   float R[] = new float[9];
   float I[] = new float[9];

  boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
   if (success) {
       float orientation[] = new float[3];
       SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
       playerAngle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(orientation[1], orientation[0]));

    }
```

Comment: Wow..I have spent too much time on the computer. The answer was simply to use the pitch.

Which in my code would be to set playerAngle to:

playerAngle = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[1]);


If anyone else runs across this, I hope it helps. I wasted a looot of time on this...

Comment: How do i get the angle from the floor?

Comment: Hi i would like to know if floor or sky  if phone facing me angle must be zero when turning phone left to right angle should calculate let me know how to calculate angle ,  i m getting azimuth ,roll but not that one i required